# "Select all text in iframe" button?

Tags: jquery, html, button, iframe, selectall

I have an iframe on a webpage. This iframe is sourced to (that is, shows the contents of) a `.txt` file on my server.

I would like to implement a button (that sits outside of the iFrame, of course) that, when clicked, *Selects All* the text in the iFrame.

Is this possible? (For example, via jQuery/JavaScript.)

Comment: The code found at the bottom of this webpage does not work: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20699826/Selecting-all-text-within-an-iframe.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a DOM property for iframes called contentDocument which returns the document object generated by a frame or iframe element.

HTML

```
<iframe id="frame" src="file.txt"></iframe>
<!-- points to the text file -->

<button id="selectText">Copy Text</button>
<!-- button to copy the text -->
```

JS

```
var selButtom = document.getElementById('selectText'); //store the button value in a variable
var frame = document.getElementById('frame'); // store iframe in variable

selButtom.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var frameContent = frame.contentDocument; // get content of iframe
    frameContent.execCommand('selectAll'); // execute select command
},false);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this code to work on JSFiddle.net, but when I implemented it on my actual website, it worked amazingly. Thanks!

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: Do you know how to make this "Select All" code work on iOS?

Comment: no sorry...could i get an upvote if my answer was helpful ?

Comment: I have not been granted the privilege of upvoting; I have not accumulated the sufficient number of reputation points. I am only permitted to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iFrameName.window` you can use any method of iframe page.

To select text, you can try https://code.google.com/p/rangy/ . Just simple replace all `document.body` to `iFrameName.window.document.body`.

Or a simple alternative way: just use `iFrameName.window.document.execCommand("selectAll")` .